# Горизонтальные колонки с многоколоночными заголовками

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть горизонтально скролящиеся колонки. В них размещён некоторый текст с заголовками. Надо сделать, чтобы каждый заголовок располагался в начале новой колонки и по ширине распространялся на все колонки, относящиеся к нему:

[image: Желаемый результат]
или так:
[image: Альтернативный желаемый результат]

Но получается только такое (да и то не работает как минимум в Firefox):

[image: Результат в хроме]

[Пробовал сделать при помощи inline-block'ов](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548849/178988), но там оказалась другая проблема. Ещё пытался использовать отрицательные margin'ы, абсолютное позиционирование и `transform`, но ничего не вышло - они остаются внутри области и не дают вылезти наверх (кроме варианта с absolute'ом относительно контейнера: там сбрасывается горизонтальное положение в колонке).

Простейший вариант кода https://jsfiddle.net/07n6L2yh/10/

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

h2 {
  break-before: column; /* Firefox? */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 .25em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum! Ea assum erroribus accommodare pri, simul omnesque scaevola has cu, an putant tacimates ius. Ius soluta nonumes ei? Ex modus eligendi repudiandae ius, nec cu quem delicatissimi.</p>

  <h2>AAA</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, explicabo.</p>

  <h2>Dolor sit</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu eirmod complectitur pri, agam libris euripidis no quo. In cum adolescens necessitatibus, et hinc nominati indoctum his, idque prompta moderatius cu per. Quo ei novum utroque, ius ex graecis volutpat quaerendum!</p>

  <h2>BBB</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>

  <h2>CCC</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>
```

Дополненная версия: https://jsfiddle.net/07n6L2yh/11/

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/38612128/4928642)

Comment: и каков вопрос?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, как сделать, чтобы получилось как на любом из двух первых скриншотов.

Comment: Как узнать сколько столбцов занимает абзац текста? Никак, имхо.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, но браузер-то знает. Хоть как-то отступы вверху колонок обеспечить и положить заголовок поверх них?

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня получилось сделать, но мой способ не работает если не устанавливать ширину места, типа ширина основного блока `width: 1000px` https://jsfiddle.net/mv1r9twg/ что-то типа такого. Попробуй на больших данных. Но ты всегда должен знать сколько должна занимать область с этим текстом)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, что-то я не понял, что именно получилось - не вижу никаких отличий от моего варианта. И ещё надо поправить `column-fill: auto;` - я вместо него в вопросе сначала `column-rule` написал.

Comment: @Qwertiy я форк не сохранил просто)) добавь к адресу `/1`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ширина колонок разная в разных блоках. И добавленный column-fill (https://jsfiddle.net/mv1r9twg/2/) игнорируется.

Comment: @Qwertiy больше у меня нет вариантов)))

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38612128/4928642

Answer (score 1):

Может быть это немного не то, что требуется, но попытка не пытка.

[Пример (jade/stylus)](http://codepen.io/lamartire/pen/mEoLpv)

Суть в том, что каждая секция с колонками - отдельный блок (как я понял из примеров, необязательно, чтобы в разметке были только p и h2), соответственно, каждая секция - независимый поток.

Разметка (обрезал рыбу):

```
<div class="text-column">
      <div class="text-column__title">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="text-column__content">
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
.text-column {
  display inline-block
  vertical-align top
  width 33%
}

.text-column__title h2 {
    margin 0 0 15px
    border-bottom 1px dotted
 }
.text-column__content {
    height 250px
    -moz-column-width 10em
    column-width 10em
    -moz-column-fill auto
    column-fill auto
}

p {
   margin 0
}
```

Контейнер заголовка (или заголовок, на самом деле это совершенно не принципиально, так как оба они являются блочными элементами) занимает 100% ширины секции, в то время, как контент тоже представляет собой блочный элемент, внутри которого лежит разбитый на колонки абзац.

Comment: В таком случае надо скриптом динамически разбивать текст на колонки, а также переразбивать заново при изменении размера. Собственно из-за этого js-тега и нет в вопросе.